# Issue with using MSBuild to build a VS2012/VS2013 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, cygwin, build-automation

I'm trying to automatically build a (currently working) Visual Studio 2013 in cygwin so that I can automatically build my project and run it.  My project is compiled using the VS2012 toolset.

I currently have this bash script running in cygwin (based off of this blog post: http://anthonykosky.blogspot.com/2013/10/making-visual-studio-solutions-cmake.html):

```
###### FIRST -- import the Visual Studio settings
export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Windows/system32"

CMD=/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/cmd
${CMD} /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"

# alias for MSBUILD
MSBUILD="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe"

# We're going to do a 64 bit release build
BUILD_CONFIG=Release
PLATFORM=x64

MSBUILD_LOG=msbuild.log

SLN_FILE=$1

"${MSBUILD}" ${SLN_FILE} /fl /property:Configuration=${BUILD_CONFIG};Platform=${PLATFORM}
msbuild_rv=$?

if [ ${msbuild_rv} != 0 ]
then
    echo "MSBuild ${SLN_FILE} exited with status '${msbuild_rv}'"
    exit 1
fi

grep -q '0 Error(s)' ${MSBUILD_LOG}
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "MSBuild ${SLN_FILE} detected errors"
    exit 1
    fi
```

When it compiles, I get the repeated error that:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in {file}.obj
```

This seems to be a mismatch between version 1800 (VS2013, which I'm creating the solution in) and 1700 (VS2012, the toolset I need to compile with).

I'm a bit confused why MSBuild isn't doing this right, because my solution is configured correctly in VS2013.  What do I need to change in my build script to ensure that it compiles?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things wrong here:

- the toolset the project is built with is specified in the project itself (`PlatformToolset` property in the project file), not by which vcvars file called on the commandline
- the `${CMD} /c ...` command does *nothing* for the script, the article you linked to is simply wrong: what it does is start a new process, execute the bat file, then terminate. Any environment variables set by the batch file are local to the process only, not to the calling process.
- it is not even needed to call vcvars before building using `msbuild <solution>`. vcvars sets up the PATH/INCLUDE/... variables so you can invoke the compiler manually on the commandline, but that is not what you are doing here: you are just building projects in which the PATH/INCLUDE/... is automatically determined by which `PlatformToolset` is used

So to summarize all of the above: just calling msbuild on your solution should be ok, you do not need to call vcvars, and I don't know exactly why you get the linker error as you don't supply enough information to figure that out but the cause is not in the script: the linker error means you are mixing object files built with different toolsets. Possibly you need to do a rebuild. Just searching for *mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value doesn't match value* gives enough search hits.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I didn't realize that about vcvars!  Regarding the error: why would it fail to compile on the command line if it compiles fine from that solution/project in Visual Studio?  What information would help figure out the cause of this error?

Comment: Not really sure. Does the problem also exist if you create a project from scratch and build that? If not, it must be something related to your project so maybe elaborate on the structure of it. Does the link error appear for one file only? Do you use external libraries? Does the link error appear for one file only? Do you use external libraries? Did you already try a proper rebuild from the commandline?  Did you go through [some of these](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mismatch+detected+for+%27_MSC_VER%27%3A+value+doesn%27t+match+value) to see if anything rings a bell?